# Changing contents of a specific parameter in a file through shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file called *local.conf*:

```
db.default.driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xyz31"
db.default.user="ron"
db.default.password=""
```

Here `xyz31` is the variable `${DB_NAME}`. I need to update only the `${DB_NAME}` which is `xyz31` (in this instance), but which varies depending on what the current of value `${DB_NAME}` is, and which needs to be updated to whatever value the user has entered, for ex:`abc22`.

```
db.default.driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abc22"
db.default.user="ron"
db.default.password=""
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Closers:  the answer to this Q. needn't be in `sed`; conflating it with a pure `sed` question greatly reduces the possible answer set.

Comment: For example... assuming whatever program is reading (and rereading) the config file is itself a shell script, changing line #2 of the config file to use parameter expansion should automatically produce the desired effect with no further code: `db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/${DB_NAME:-xyz31}"`

Comment: This didn't work, it won't know which file to edit and there is no file name

Comment: More information is needed.  What the name of the program that reads the config file?  What programming language is that program written in?

Comment: Re *"...and there is no file name"*: not sure what you mean; please specify which filename you're referring to.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` should be enough:

```sh
i=abc22 # or input from user by read i
sed "/^db.default.url/s/$DB_NAME/$i/" local.conf
```

Add `-i` option if you want to make change to the file.

Comment: I need to cheange it everytime the the script is run. Here xyz31 is the variable {DB_NAME} and it should be updated to abc22 based on what user is entered.

Comment: OK, just updated.

Comment: This only replaces `db.default.driver` i.e
`abc22="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xyz31"`

Answer (score 0):

Use an editor like Unix' `sed(1)`:

```
  sed -i -e 's;xyz31;abc22; /your/funny/file/here
```

Might need to decorate with word beginning/end to avoid false positive matches (check your manual what is available). And/or write out another file and check with `diff(1)` that the change is right.

Comment: I need to cheange it everytime the the script is run. Here xyz31 is the variable {DB_NAME} and it should be updated to abc22 based on what user is entered.